# List<String>- Null

Tags: android

I am trying to iterate List from JSON. And everything works fine when List is not null. When is null, i ve got this: **Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference**

```
 StringBuilder allAlsoAvailable = new StringBuilder();
            List<String> alsoAvailableList = example.getResult().getAlsoAvailableOn();
                    for (int i = 0; i < alsoAvailableList.size(); i++) {
                        allAlsoAvailable.append(alsoAvailableList.get(i));
                        if (i < alsoAvailableList.size() - 1) allAlsoAvailable.append("\n");
                    }
```

and LogCat shows that the problem is in this line: `for (int i = 0; i < alsoAvailableList.size(); i++)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Builder allAlsoAvailable = new StringBuilder();
List<String> alsoAvailableList = example.getResult().getAlsoAvailableOn();
if (alsoAvailableList != null) {
  for (int i = 0; i < alsoAvailableList.size(); i++) {
     allAlsoAvailable.append(alsoAvailableList.get(i));
     if (i < alsoAvailableList.size() - 1) allAlsoAvailable.append("\n");
  }
}
```

As your error explains, you can't call methods on a null object, in this case your `alsoAvailableList` is null, so make sure it's not null first when trying to use it.

Answer (score 1):

This is because, as the error states, your `alsoAvailableList` is null and you are trying to access it's method `size()`.

You should first check if the list is null and then iterate through it.

For example:

```
Builder allAlsoAvailable = new StringBuilder();
List<String> alsoAvailableList = example.getResult().getAlsoAvailableOn();
if (alsoAvailableList != null) {
  for (int i = 0; i < alsoAvailableList.size(); i++) {
     allAlsoAvailable.append(alsoAvailableList.get(i));
     if (i < alsoAvailableList.size() - 1) allAlsoAvailable.append("\n");
  }
}
```